# Directly attributable code coverage?

Tags: unit-test

Since the last release, when I execute a single unit test (via Develop > Apex Classes > Test Class > Run Test), I get taken to the "Apex Test Execution" screen. This screen shows whether the test passed or failed, but not the line coverage directly attributable to this unit test.

Previously, when you executed a single unit test you would get a full list of classes and the coverage % you got from that single unit test.

Other than doing a "Clear Code Coverage" (which takes forever), then running a single unit test, then going back to the Apex Classes view, is there a simple way to just see the coverage directly attributable to one run of a test class? If not this seems like a big regression in developer-facing functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is now available in [test execution available the Developer Console](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_dev_console_test_runs_creating.htm).

[image]

Comment: Am I right in seeing that you can get test-method-level attributable code coverage, and global-level code coverage, but not test-level coverage? I want to see the total coverage my entire test class gives across all methods, like I had before, but that seems to no longer be possible?

Comment: @jkraybill - Your are correct.  You only get the report at the individual unit test level when viewing the test detail, but not the test class.  I haven't see it and don't see it in the docs either.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in SF that has the functionality you are looking for anymore. Can you run the test through the IDE instead?  The [Apex Test Runner's test results window](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_IDE#Testing) reports at the class level.

Comment: Yeah I can; I have avoided that in the past because I used to notice coverage discrepancies between the IDE and the UI, and the UI was always in line with the numbers I got back from code deployments. Hope that's still not the case.