# Is that possible to make the apex class code coverage to zero with out edit and save the page?

Tags: apex

I am fixing all the test classes start with `IT_` coverage in my org.

The failed class is already covered by some other handler class. So its now 80%.

Now i want to re-set all class to 0 to test my test class able to cover. It happen only when i click edit and save the original class.

is that possible to re-set all class coverage reset to 0 at once?

i tried service console to write a simple code on ApexTrigger and apex class  object and update statement but **DML not allowed on this [Tooling API checkbox enabled]**.

```
update ([SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexTrigger WHERE Name LIKE 'IT_%']);
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: Seems like the same question as [Directly attributable code coverage?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/directly-attributable-code-coverage)

Answer (score 6):

Go to Apex Test Execution and once you get through any dialogues, you should get a screen that shows a list of all executed tests labeled Apex Test Results. It will have a button on it labeled "Clear Test Data". Click on that to clear your results for individual Test Classes. The screen shot below is from an org with Lightning Enabled.

[image: Apex Test Results Screen Capture]